# Return position and highlighting of search queries in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search, lucene, elasticsearch-php, fast-vector-highlighter

I am using the official Elasticsearch-PHP client installed on a personal Debian server, and what I am trying to do involves indexing, searching and highlighting individual documents. i.e. each search result will only return one document - which will then be highlighted for "simple query string" searches. I am also using FVH (fast vector highlighting).

My question is similar to this one [Position as result, instead of highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49751209/position-as-result-instead-of-highlighting) and the test code is basically the same so I won't repeat that here. However in my case I need **both** position and highlighting. I followed the link to the documentation about term vectors, but just like the other OP, my searches are not exact words *per se*. In some cases they are phrases. How would I approach this?

My use case is to search only one document (for each query), and present a summary of results with links which the user can click to go to the specific place in the document where that result came from. If I have the index / position I can simply use that against the full source of the document. I have checked the documentation to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to install a specific plugin developed by **wikimedia foundation** called **Experimental Highlighter** -github [here](https://github.com/wikimedia/search-highlighter)

You can install for elasticsearch 7.5 in this way - for other elasticsearch versions please refer to the github project page:

```
./bin/elasticsearch-plugin install org.wikimedia.search.highlighter:experimental-highlighter-elasticsearch-plugin:7.5.1
```

And restart elasticsearch.

Inasmuch you need to retrieve also the `positions` - if for your use case the offsets can replace the positions please go on to the next paragraph - you should declare your field with termvector with the index option  `"with_position_offset_payloads"` - doc [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html)

```
PUT /my-index-000001
{ "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "text": {
        "type": "text",
        "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets_payloads",
        "analyzer" : "fulltext_analyzer"
       }
     }
   }
}
```

For other cases that don't need to retrieve also the position, it is faster and uses much less space to use the index option `"offsets"` - elastic doc [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/highlighting.html#offsets-strategy), plugin doc [here](https://github.com/wikimedia/search-highlighter#offsets-in-postings-or-term-vectors):

```
PUT /my-index-000001
{ "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "text": {
        "type": "text",
        "index_options": "offsets",
        "analyzer" : "fulltext_analyzer"
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Then you could query with the experimental highlighter and return only offset of the highlighter part:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": "hello world"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "order": "score",
    "fields": {
      "text": {
        "number_of_fragments": 10,
        "fragment_size": 15,
        "type": "experimental",
        "options": {"return_offset": true}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this way no text is returned from your query but only the `start offset` and the `end offset` - numbers that represent position. To retrieve your highlighted content you need to enter inside `['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['text']` -text is your field name - and extract text from the field using your start offset point and the end offset point. You need to ensure to use the correct string encoding - `UTF-8` - otherwise the offsets don't match text. According to the doc:

> The return_offsets option changes the results from a highlighted
> string to the offsets in the highlighted that would have been
> highlighted. This is useful if you need to do client side sanity
> checking on the highlighting. Instead of a marked up snippet you'll
> get a result like 0:0-5,18-22:22. The outer numbers are the start and
> end offset of the snippet. The pairs of numbers separated by the ,s
> are the hits. The number before the - is the start offset and the
> number after the - is the end offset. Multi-valued fields have a
> single character worth of offset between them.

Let me know if that plugin could help!

Comment: This looks like a great idea! I will try it out and get back to you to accept the answer. P.S. I use ElasticSearch 7.8 so I am not sure about backward-compatibility with 7.5 but I'm hopeful.

Comment: So? Have you try with the plugin? I have used it in the past, if you have any doubt I can help you

Comment: Thank you so much! I may take you up on that actually, if I need help. No I haven't tried yet - my boss switched me to some other urgent tasks until Friday so I will do this on Thursday / Friday and if I run into any problems I will let you know.

Comment: Sorry for the late response... It's been almost 2 years but I have finally been put back on this project! Unfortunately, this plugin doesn't seem to be compatible with 7.17 which is the version in use. So I am unable to install it. Any other hints or tips will be very welcome, thank you!

Comment: Is there a typo which can be fixed like `"options": {"return_offsets": true}` ? (I do not know, I just turn what looks like a non-answer comment meant on this post here, by a low rep user, into a comment here.)